# SWRevealViewController - Current Frontviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, swrevealviewcontroller

In my project , I used SWRevealviewcontroller for slider menu.and when Project is in background and then Foreground that time i want current front view object.

How to get current front viewcontroller from SWRevealviewcontroller ?

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]  init];

    NSLog(@"front :%@",mainRevealController.frontViewController);
 }
```

Comment: can you show your storyboard scene once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik do you want image file?

Comment: ya bro.........., actually kishore answer working fine , but assume that if you are in non SWL viewcontroller, on that time it goes to wrong view or it is called in every time whenever you goes and again come to foreground'

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController *root = [window rootViewController];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = root.storyboard;
CustomViewController *vcc =(CustomViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardID"];

[root presentModalViewController:vcc animated:YES];
}
```

When your app become active pass the ViewController to front ,this method is present inside the appdelegate